# Eclipse JCOP Tools Error - "no definition for label Label: 15659979, , block 230, def null"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javacard, jcop

I am working on JavaCard applet and I am facing a strange error in my NXP JCOP Tools Eclipse plugin:

[image]

It says: "no definition for label Label: XXXXXXXX, , block XXX, def null".

Do you have any idea what it could mean? Eclipse underlines the package name, but I am absolutely sure that the package name is correct and that the class is in the correct package. There is no other error in the whole project (From 11 errors above there are 2 of type "no definition for label Label: ..." and other 9 directly caused by these 2). I tried cleaning and refreshing the project and deleting all binaries, but it does not help.

In the "Type" column there is: "com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse.jcopmarker".

My Eclipse version:
Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, I hope it might help someone. I changed my method code from

```
public boolean processAPDU(APDU apdu) {
    final byte[] apduBuf = apdu.getBuffer();

    switch(apduBuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
...
```

to

```
public boolean processAPDU(APDU apdu) {
    final byte[] apduBuf = apdu.getBuffer();

    final byte ins = apduBuf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

    switch(ins) {
...
```

and the error is gone. Possibly a bug in NXP JCOP Tools?

Comment: It's a surprising for me as both the code blocks are same as per logic, only in second block you just store the OFFSET_INS value to a variable ins and pass that variable to the Switch statement, I do not understand why this error is solved after doing only this change. Can you, please explain me?

Comment: I do not understand it either. It really helped, however. We should probably ask someone from NXP...